# $M\cong N$ iff $[M:N]_R$ is a principal fractional ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a Dedekind ring, $K$ its field of fractions, $U$ a finite vector space over $K$, and $M,N$ finitely generated $R$-modules that span $U$, i.e. contain a basis of $U$.

For every $\mathfrak p \subset R$, define $[M:N]_{\mathfrak p} = (\det \phi_{\mathfrak p})$, where $\phi_{\mathfrak p}$ is a linear transformation that takes $M_{\mathfrak p}$ onto $N_{\mathfrak p}$. Recall here $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a principal ideal domain $\Rightarrow$ $M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}$ are free and one can indeed find such a transformation.

Now define $[M:N]_R := \prod_i \mathfrak p_i^{v_{\mathfrak p_i}([M:N]_{\mathfrak p_i})}$. According to Froehlich, one can show that $M\cong N$ iff $[M:N]_R$ is a principal fractional ideal.

One direction is easy. If we have a general linear transformation $\Psi$ of $U$ such that $\Psi (M)=N$, then $(\det \phi_{\mathfrak p_i}) = (\det \Psi_{\mathfrak p_i})$ for every $i$, so that $[M:N]_R =\prod_i \mathfrak p_i^{v_{\mathfrak p_i}([M:N]_{\mathfrak p_i})} = (\det \Psi)$, which is a principal fractional ideal.

But how do I get the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

First consider the case $\dim U=1$. Let $[M:N]_R=\alpha R$. By localizing it is then easy to see that $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is an isomorphism $M\cong N$.

Now for the general case: Let $n=\dim U$. An isomorphism $\phi_{\frak p}:M_{\frak p} \to N_{\frak p}$ induces an isomorphism $\wedge^nM_{\frak p}\to \wedge^n N_{\frak p}\subset \wedge^nU$ with the same determinant, so $[\wedge^nM:\wedge^nN]_R=[M:N]_R$. By the dimension $1$ case we conclude $\wedge^nM\cong\wedge^nN$. From this it follows that $M\cong N$. E.g. we can write $M\cong R^{n-1}\oplus I$, $N\cong R^{n-1}\oplus J$ for ideals $I,J$ and then $I\cong \wedge^nM\cong\wedge^nN\cong J$, so $M\cong N$.