# module index is principal implies isomorphic modules

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the book of Froehlich and Cassels, there is a claim at the end of page 10 saying that two modules are isomorphic if and only if the module index is a principal fractional ideal.  It's easy to show that the module index is principal if we are give two isomorphic modules, but how to show the other direction?  i.e. how to prove that $M\cong N$ if $[M:N]$ is a principal fractional ideal?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To make your question self-contained, please give the *full context* of the result: over what kind of ring are your modules $M$ and $N$ being considered, are the modules just totally abstract or are they assumed to live inside some common space (e.g., inside a common vector space over some field), and what do you mean by the module index $[M:N]$? A special case of your result, where the modules are taken to be ideals in an integral domain, is Theorem 5.2 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/moduleintro.pdf.

Comment: Hi, KCd, thanks for your comment.  I just found a same question here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639861/m-cong-n-iff-mn-r-is-a-principal-fractional-ideal?rq=1)  There are the details of setting up for this question, but unfortunately it wasn't answered.